# Determining the magnitude of forces acting on an object with no net force

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

Here is a screenshot of the problem:

[image: Problem picture]

I understand we can write the vectors as say:
$\mathbf{F_1} = \Vert \mathbf{F_1} \Vert \langle \cos\theta, \sin\theta \rangle$

I also know this problem requires us to add up all the forces and set that equal to 0 (as there is no net force on the object). What I am having troubles with is how to set up which vectors with which angles. Any suggestions?

Comment: The horizontal component of $F_2$ is $|F_2|\cos 45.$ The horizontal component of the force of magnitude $20$ $lbs$ is $20\cos 30.$ Since there is no net force it must be $|F_2|\cos 45=20\cos 30.$ Can you make the same with the vertical components?

Comment: @mfl I understand how you got those components but what about accounting for direction? In the second case we would get a positive x component which it seems to me should be negative?

Comment: @mfl ah I see, by equating the two you are accounting for the negative, sorry please disregard my previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you break your vector into 2 vectors, one parallel to the floor,and second vertical.

For F2 you get Fv and Fh, you look those vectors as sides of triangle, and uses sin and cos, so cos(45)=Fh/F2 and sin(45)=-Fv/F2.

- Fh-horizontal force, Fv- vertical force
- I consider pozitive direction from left to right and from down to up (that's why Fv is negative).

On other side ,for F3=20lbs, sin(30)=-Fv'/F3 and cos(30)=-Fh'/F3.

Now the sum of up down forces is zero , and sum of right/left is zero.

F1+(-Fv)+(-Fv')=0
Fh+(-Fh')=0